# xkb: Use a key to change shift level without appearing as a modifier

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

I'd like to configure XKB to use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as a way of producing different keys, but I don't want it to appear as a modifier.  For example:

- <kbd>F1</kbd> produces `F21` keypress
- <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> produces `F1` keypress (i.e. no modifiers)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> produces `Shift + F1` keypress (only `Shift` counts as a modifier)

I have partially succeeded with this by assigning <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to `Hyper_R`, but the problem is this only works if `Hyper_R` is also set as a modifier, e.g. `Mod3`.  This means <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> actually produces `Shift + Mod3 + F1` so any hotkeys listening for `Shift + F1` don't work because they don't like `Mod3` being present.

Is there any way I can use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to change they behaviour of certain keys, without actually having it appear to an X application as a modifier key?

The docs I have read hint that this is possible with advanced XKB configuration but I can't find any details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, this is ancient, but perhaps even if it's too late for you, someone else may find this hint useful:

In your `types`, add:

```
type "CapsShiftSpecial" {
    modifiers= Shift+Hyper;

    map[Shift]= Level2;
    preserve[Shift]= Shift;

    map[Hyper]= Level3;

    map[Shift+Hyper]= Level4;
    preserve[Shift+Hyper]= Shift;

    level_name[Level1]= "Base";
    level_name[Level2]= "Shift";
    level_name[Level3]= "Hyper";
    level_name[Level4]= "Shift Hyper";
};
```

Then, in the `symbols` file, have something like

```
key <FK01>  { type[group1]="CapsShiftSpecial",
              symbols[group1]=[ F21, F21, F1, F1 ]};
```

A program monitoring the keystrokes (`xev` or `emacs`, for example) will see the keypresses as though you pressed **F21**, **Shift+F21**, **F1**, and **Shift+F1**.

Comment: Thanks - for all the things I'd read, this is the first time I understand what `preserve` can do!